# Could not load key file. File 'id_rsa.pub' could not be loaded or does not contain a private key. - File Zilla

Tags: sftp, amazon-web-services, filezilla, public-key, private-key

While trying to connect to AWS instance using SFTP, it gives me an error while setting the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file for connection.

Error - `Could not load key file. File 'id_rsa.pub' could not be loaded or does not contain a private key. - File Zilla`

Comment: And what is the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realized that it needed a private file (key) to be given for setting up SFTP connection.
`~/.ssh/id_rsa` is the private file
`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is the public file
One has to use the private file for FileZilla to connect.

Comment: I have an active ~/.ssh/id_rsa private key file that I use to ssh into my server, but I get this same error message when I try to set this in FileZilla. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Do you mean it says "Could not load key file. File 'id_rsa' could not be loaded or does not contain a private key. - File Zilla"?

Comment: yes. That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: This is very weird coz id_rsa is the private key file and only possible explanation is that it might be corrupt for some reason. Can you try downloading the pem file or creating a new pem file and using that?

Comment: Not so. If my private `id-rsa` file was corrupt then I would not be able to use it many times every day to ssh into several servers. But heh, I'm just reporting what I am experiencing, not trying to explain the problem. If someone has a similar problem as me, then try my answer below.

Comment: Alright.. makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS FileZilla wouldn't accept my active private key stored at `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, but when I set the Logon Type to `Interactive` I could connect without a password.

Comment: I use MacOS and FileZilla does accept private key. More importantly, to connect to AWS you ideally should need a pem file (from security standpoint)

Answer (score 0):

While this is a bit old and the accepted answer is somewhat correct, it still doesn't solve the issue. However, it will work fine if you use the absolute path.

```
/users/username/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Some background to the story, while using `~/.ssh/id_rsa` it still returns the same error even though the file exists, as I use it to connect via the terminal.

```
Could not be loaded or does not contain a private key.
```